# Displaying separate tables in the same MVC-view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have created two different tables with entity. 
The code looks like this:

```
public class Frisorer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Scheman> Schema { get; set; }
    }

    public class Scheman
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Schemat { get; set; }
        public virtual Frisorer frisorer { get; set; }
    }
```

My context file:

```
 public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
{
}
    public DbSet<Frisorer> Frisorer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Scheman> Scheman { get; set; }
}
```

The tables get created allright with keys establishing a relationship between them.
  What i would like now is to be able to display both the names/id of my frisor and their schemas in the same view in MVC. But when i try to add a view, I can only choose strongly typed views with either Frisorer OR Schemas...How can I do to display both my tables together?

EDIT:

I created a new class where I encaosulated the two other classes:

```
public class Frisorer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Scheman> Schema { get; set; }
    }

    public class Scheman
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Schemat { get; set; }
        public virtual Frisorer frisorer { get; set; }
    }

    public class BigViewModel
    {
        public List<Frisorer> Frisorer { get; set; }
        public List<Scheman> Scheman { get; set; }
    }
```

And the controll:

```
public ActionResult hopp()
        {

            BigViewModel bv = new BigViewModel();
            bv.Frisorer = (from o in cont.Frisorer select o).ToList();
            bv.Scheman = (from or in cont.Scheman select or).ToList();
            return View(bv);

        }
```

I create a view where I choose BigViewModel as the strongly typed and list as scaffolding.
Get this error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication3.Models.BigViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication3.Models.BigViewModel]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you are passing an single `object` to the view when the view is expecting a collection of `BigViewModel`.

Try changeing the modelbinding in your view to: `@model BigViewModel` instead of `@model IEnumerable<BigViewModel>` and then iterate the collections in your `Model`:

```
@foreach(var frisor in Model.Frisorer)
{
   //do stuff
}

@foreach(var schema in Model.Scheman)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a third class, some kind of a ViewModel/Wrapper, that will encapsulate everything you need. Reference it then in your View.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to do that in an answer please?
Been looking online but most of the sites i've seen requires that I change everything..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the model in the view from `@model IEnumerable<BigViewModel>` to `@model BigViewModel` and then iterate over `Frisorer` and `Scheman`, something like so:

```
@model BigViewModel

<ul>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Frisorer) 
    {
        <li>@item.Id - @item.Name</li>
    }
</ul>

<ul>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Scheman) 
    {
        <li>@item.Id - @item.Schemat</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @BiffBaffBoff, How to displays the 2 tables in same table.?. Is that possible?